# Display wiremock current configuration in older version

Tags: java, mocking, wiremock

I need to display the current Wiremock configuration in a project (type of mocks, mocks configuration, etc...). What command can I use?

The only thing I've found is the `WireMockRuntimeInfo` object, but only in the latest versions of Wiremock. Unfortunately, I can only use `2.11.0` in my project. Is there something equivalent?

Comment: Are you using that with JUnit or running as standalone?

Comment: it seems running with junit 4 but for completeness show me both cases

Comment: Can you provide maven/gradle configuration file to question? Need to find the dependencies you have used.